# how to insert a db in sqlite3? shows error

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, ios5

I'm trying to insert my data into db.db created successfully but data not insert into the database.but the data successfully goes to insertsql after that showing error.pls check my code

```
-(void)insertDB
{
NSString *dname=[[NSString alloc]init];
dname=[delegate.Name objectAtIndex:0];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath=[delegate.databasepath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO STABLE (NAME) VALUES (\"%@\")",dname];

    //insert sql is ok,after that they shows error

    const char *insert_stmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];

    NSLog(@"const char%@",insert_stmt);

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement,NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {

        NSLog(@"saved");
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"data" message:@"saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        [self counting];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to add new favourites");
        NSLog(@"Failed to update row %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
[self loadmusic];
```

}

Comment: insert databaseINSERT INTO STABLE (NAME) VALUES (" MUSIC")
2012-11-13 01:10:01.369 [35050:707] Failed to add new favourites
2012-11-13 01:10:01.371 [35050:707] Failed to update row no such table: STABLE

Comment: So did you ever create the table?

Comment: (Have you read any of the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)?

Comment: CREATE TABLE STABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,NAME VACHAR(50) );

Comment: Dump you DB and see if it's there the way you think it should be.

Comment: (Keep in mind that if you "create" a DB in the "bundle" directory, it will not really exist.  It must be created in one of the R/W directories for the app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the error message returned is:

> Failed to update row no such table: STABLE

And, well, the problem is exactly that: there is no table called `STABLE`. You've clearly managed to connect to a database but there is no table there with the name that you expect.

The real question is *how* and *when* did you create the table? Chances are the database you're connected to is not the one you think is being used.